# Customize Odoo 10 Point Of sale print out

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

This is standart odoo point of sale print out

[image: odoo Point of sale print out]

I want to change / customize odoo print out by my version.

Someone could please show me the way ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can inherite the base code or else change in base code of pos.template Apart from that you can also go through odoo app store there are some free apps are available for this too.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the template /odoo/addons/point_of_sale/views/report_saledetails.xml or create your own module and inherit the point_of_sale module and then change what you want